# after updating my mysql jdbc jar my inserts with dates is no long working

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have just updated my jdbc driver and a number of my inserts and updates are no longer working. i did find that if i put this in my etc/my.cnf it helped with some.

```
sql_mode=ALLOW_INVALID_DATES
```

But i am still having problems with date and time fields that allow null

for example when i try to insert

```
insert into calendar2 (`id`,  `userID`,  `title`,  `event_desc`,  `catid`,
                       `startDate`,  `startTime`,  `endDate`,  `endTime`,
                       `allDayEvent`,  `url`,  `image`,  `icon`,  `recurrence`,
                       `occuranceID`,  `endRecurDate`) 
               values ( '0' ,'965' ,'asd' ,'asd' ,'-1' ,'2014-06-11' 
                         ,'','','','1' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'0' ,'' )
```

This used to work. now i get the error

```
Data truncation: Incorrect time value: '' for column 'startTime' at row 1
```

this is legacy code and the sql is generated. I can not change it to parameterized

the fields are defined in the DB as

```
`startDate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`startTime` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`endDate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`endTime` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
```

in my jdbc connect string i have

```
jdbc:mysql://HOST:3306/DB?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

Thanks for any help or ideas

Answer (score 0):

fyi finally found the answer
found it here http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/kathleen/classes/cs3200/connector-j.pdf

i needed to set these vars

```
emptyStringsConvertToZero=true
jdbcCompliantTruncation=false
noDatetimeStringSync=true
nullCatalogMeansCurrent=true
nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true
transformedBitIsBoolean=false
dontTrackOpenResources=true
zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
useServerPrepStmts=false
autoClosePStmtStreams=true
processEscapeCodesForPrepStmts=false
useFastDateParsing=false
populateInsertRowWithDefaultValues=false
useDirectRowUnpack=false
```